# ElasticSearch - Unable to fetch mapping

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I have set up an ELK stack to index my Akamai Logs.  I have created a conf file in Logstash and am loading it when I load Logstash.  My log file simply reads

> Pipeline main started

However, I am unable to create the index in Kibana.  I see the message

> Unable to fetch mapping

I ran my grok statement through a debugger and it seemed like I captured everything.  Here is my config:

```
    input {
  file {
    path => "C:\Akamai_Logs\US\*"
    start_position => "beginning"
  }
}

filter {
  grok {
    match => ["message", "%{DATE:date} %{TIME:time} %{IP:client} %{WORD:method} %{URIPATH:URI} %{NUMBER:status} %{NUMBER:bytes} %{NUMBER:time_taken} %{NOTSPACE:refererr} %{QS:user_agent} %{GREEDYDATA:cookie}"]
  }
}


output {
  stdout {codec => rubydebug}
  elasticsearch {
      hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
    }

}
```

Here is a sample line from one of the logs

> 2016-06-14 14:03:42 1.1.1.1 GET /origin-uri 200 26222 0 "referrer" "user agent" "cookie string"

Could the spacing in the log file cause any issues indexing?  Am I just missing something else?

EDIT: Forgot to add my Logstash template

```
{
    "template": "logstash-*",
    "settings" : {
        "number_of_shards" : 1,
        "number_of_replicas" : 0,
        "index" : {
            "query" : { "default_field" : "@message" },
            "store" : { "compress" : { "stored" : true, "tv": true } }
        }
    },
    "mappings": {
        "_default_": { 
            "_all": { "enabled": false },
            "_source": { "compress": true },
            "dynamic_templates": [
                {
                    "string_template" : { 
                        "match" : "*",
                        "mapping": { "type": "string", "index": "not_analyzed" },
                        "match_mapping_type" : "string"
                     } 
                 }
             ],
             "properties" : {
                "@date": { "type": "date", "format": "yyyy-MM-dd" },
                "@time": { "type": "time", "format": "hh:mm:ss" },
                "@hostip": {"type": "string","index" : "not_analyzed"},    
                "@method": {"type": "string","index" : "not_analyzed"},
                "@page": {"type": "string","index" : "not_analyzed"},
                "@status": {"type": "integer"},
                "@bytes": {"type": "integer"},
                "@timetaken": {"type": "integer"},
                "@referrer": {"type": "string","index" : "not_analyzed"},
                "@useragent": {"type": "string","index" : "not_analyzed"},
                "@cookie": {"type": "string","index" : "not_analyzed"}              
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your `file` input with this one (use forward slashes instead of backslashes), then it should work.

```
input {
  file {
    path => "C:/Akamai_Logs/US/*.*"
    start_position => "beginning"
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**

Since you have your own index template file, make sure to modify your `elasticsearch` output like this:

```
output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
        template => "/path/to/logstash-template.json"
        template_overwrite => true
    }
}
```

Also maybe make sure to delete the logstash template if one already exists in your ES

```
curl -XDELETE localhost:9200/_template/logstash
```

Comment: Thank you for the response Val.  Still not able to fetch the mapping.  Will the index be created as "logstash-"?

Comment: Where did you get the index template in your question from? Directly from your ES or from a file? If the latter what's its name?

Comment: It is a file stored in my Logstash directory.  The file name is logstash-template.json

Comment: Then you need to add `template => "/path/to/logstash-template.json"` and `template_overwrite => true` to your `elasticsearch` output (see [more info](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-elasticsearch.html#plugins-outputs-elasticsearch-template)).

Comment: so no matter which template I use (mine or default logstash) I cannot get data to go to Elastic.  I ran logstash with debug and I can see it reading the file line by line, but the index is never created.

Comment: If you ran in debug mode, what do you see concerning the `elasticsearch` output? And you're sure that your ES is up and running and reachable from your Logstash host?

Comment: I know the connection is fine because I just got something basic to create an index.  input {
    file {
        path => "C:/Logs/*.*"
        start_position => beginning 
    }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
 index => "test"
 }
}

Comment: the new index is called test.

Comment: closer.  My last error was "no handler for type time." I changed this to a string.

Comment: After continuing to debug and clearing sincedb, it looks like I have a grok parse failure.

Comment: You should better use the `QUOTEDSTRING` pattern for your last three tokens (i.e. referrer, user_agent and possibly the cookie string).

Comment: here is what my message looks like after trying to parse.  This is the first half.

2016-06-14\t14:03:59\tIP\tGET\t/origin-site/en-US/products/%20Images/Final%20Product%20Image%20Library/site%site%20True%20Dimensions%/h-l.png\t302\t952\t0\t\"

Comment: so I got it working by adding double quotes around the individual items in the pattern.  However, none of my fields show up in Kibana.